# How is the memory allocation after killing a thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading, garbage-collection

If you have a thread and the thread is causing some possible memory leaks, If you kill the thread, will all the memory will be released? I am trying to understand how does the clean up works?

Comment: There is no way to conclusively answer this question with this little amount of information. It *may* be that the memory is eligible for collection, but it *depends*. We would have to have a much more detailed picture of what the thread is doing and how before anything resembling a proper answer can be made. You should run a memory profiler against your software and see where the memory is being held.

Comment: Please note that ultimately it is the *process* that owns the memory, unless the memory is held specifically by references that ties it to this thread, such as local variables, thread static fields, etc. then killing the thread won't actually deallocate anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you resort to killing a thread in the `Thread.Abort()` sense, you're pretty much saying "this process is so ill that I'm about to put it out of its misery", in which case it *really doesn't matter* what the memory semantics are. Killing a thread is a **very bad thing**, and can violate a large number of things we think about in terms of how code behaves.

But: in terms of how *memory* behaves; threads (and specifically: the active portion of the stack, and any thread-static values / thread slots) are one of many kinds of "root". Killing a thread will logically remove one root, so the *next time* GC runs, if something was *only* alive because it was directly or indirectly reachable from the stack-frame / thread-statics / thread-slots of that thread, then it will be eligible for collection. Of course, killing a thread in this way may actually *increase* problems, especially for unmanaged code - since it can stop `using` / `Dispose()` code working correctly, meaning that more finalizers may need to run. The stack space itself may *also* be recoverable, but in the grand scheme of things, that tends to me negligible - and the process may wish to keep hold of it on the basis that you'll probably want another thread.

Again: emphasis, **do not kill threads**. If you can set a signal somewhere that they check periodically and *unwind themselves*, then: fine.